# Excel LOOKUP from top to bottom of range

Tags: arrays, excel

My range is:

```
A1=0
A2=-2
A3=3
A4=0
A5=0
```

Formula in B1 is:

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/((A1:A5>0)-(A1:A5<0)))
```

The result is 1 because formula search from Bottom to Top of range `A1:A5`, if firstly appear a value `>0` or `<0`, in this case `A3=3`

How do I search from Top to Bottom of range `A1:A5`, getting as a result `-1`?

Comment: Searching from Top to Bottom first conditon met is number <0 because A2=-2, so result is -1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the *location* of the first non-zero value in the column, *(the row number)*, use:

```
=MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(A1:A5<>0,),0)
```

To get the *value* at that location, use:

```
=INDEX(A1:A5,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(A1:A5<>0,),0))
```

[image]